# Как установить права пользователей к создаваемому каналу discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хочу при создании текстового канала изменить права пользователей для него, а конкретно запретить всем участникам видеть этот канал за исключением одного, который так же может в него писать.
Код:

```
    guild = bot.get_guild(880008097370865706)
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Фермы")
    
    overwrites = {

    }
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'⛏{member.name}-{farm}', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
```

Что должно быть в словаре overwrites? В [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_text_channel#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) я не нашел параметров для этих целей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
guild = bot.get_guild(880008097370865706)
category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Фермы")

overwrites = {

}
channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'⛏{member.name}-{farm}', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, read_messages=False) # это установит роле @everyone запрет на просмотр чата
user=bot.fetch_user(id пользователя, которому надо дать права)
await channel.set_permissions(user, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
```